# Assume that $\overline{A}$ convex, is $A$ convex?

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ be bounded subset of $\mathbb{C}^d$.

It is clear that if $A$ is convex then so is $\overline{A}$. Here $\overline{A}$ denotes the closure of $A$.

> Assume that $\overline{A}$ convex, is $A$ convex?

Comment: $[-1,1] \setminus \{0\}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  In fact $\overline{A}$ convex doesn't even force $A$ connected.  Let $d = 1$ and $A$ be the two intervals $[-1,0) \cup (0,1]$ on the real axis, which isn't even connected...

Answer (score 3):

Certainly not.

Let $B$ be a convex set with nonempty interior, and let $A=B\setminus\{b\}$ where $b$ is an interior point of $B$.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Let $A = \{ z \in \Bbb C \mid \vert z \vert \leq 1, z = x+iy, x, y \in \Bbb Q \}.$